# How do I register an Angular Component?

Tags: angularjs

With the current strategy, at the root of each module I have an index.js file defining all of the **Angular 1.X** pieces are to be included within the application.

A very basic example is:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(require('./app.states'))
  .service('appService', require('./app.service'))
  .directive('appDirective', require('./app.directive'));
```

The team has been using directives for stuff that is simply silly. I'm sure you can relate to people stuffing controllers with too much and all the other bad examples for 'not having enough time'.

I'm wanting to start using components over directives for many instances where we're really just wanting a 'smart' template for a state yet it doesn't seem like I can refer to or register a component in the same way that I would the service/directive like in the example above.

In short, using 'appComponent' as the name of the component from within the state definition isn't something that works in the same way ::

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(require('./app.states'))
  .service('appService', require('./app.service'))
  .component('appComponent', require('./app.component'));
```

What should I try next?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with components? Btw, they are essentially directives with sugar syntax.

Comment: nothing is wrong...wanting to move over to using them however 'injecting' them into the code base with browserify isn't supporting the .component syntax

Comment: What do you mean by 'supporting'? Browserify is unaware of Angular or any other JS code where it is used. You have syntax error with unclosed parentheses btw.

Comment: fat-fingered the demo...updated the parens

Comment: what I meant by 'supporting' is the method angular.module(xxx, []).component() wasn't working...turns out our version 1.4.8 doesn't support it...I think my question is incorrect...going to reformat it to be 'helpful'

Comment: That's correct, components were introduced in 1.5. There is a polyfill for <1.5 https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-component

Comment: yes! https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that in the earlier versions of Angular from 1.5 on, components gained support. As it stands, to register a component within the angular module definition, you still use the directive() and simply require the component in lieu of the directive.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(require('./app.states'))
  .service('appService', require('./app.service'))
  .directive('appComponent', require('./app.component'));
```